# css first-child selector help

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to highlight the first link, and only the first link, directly below a list item with class "selected"?

Here is my [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q9sq/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, use

```
.selected > a:first-child {
    /* CSS */
}
```

`>` limits the selector to direct children.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first-child selector.

```
.selected > a:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

You can use `nth-child()` to do this as well.

```
.selected > a:nth-child(1) {
    color: red;
}
```

or

```
.selected > a:nth-child(1n - 1) {
    color: red;
}
```

:)

Comment: That `nth-child` stuff is powerful.

Answer (score 0):

```
.selected > a:first-child {color:red;}
```

This should work in your case.

Comment: Just the first child. Needs a :first-child pseudo selector.